# When two non-equivalent binary forms primitively represent the same infinite subset of the integers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $F(x,y)$ be an irreducible binary form with integer coefficients, degree $d \geq 3$ and content 1. We say that an integer $n$ is primitively represented by $F$ if there exist coprime integers $x$ and $y$ such that $F(x,y)=n$. We also say that a subset $\mathcal S \subset \mathbb Z$ is primitively represented by $F$ if every $n \in \mathcal S$ is primitively represented by $F$.

Next, for any matrix

$$A = \left(\begin{matrix}a & b\\c & d\end{matrix}\right)$$

with rational entries, define

$$F_A(x,y) = F(ax + by, cx + dy).$$

We say that two binary forms $F$ and $G$ are *equivalent* if there exists $A \in \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ such that $F_A = G$.

I am interested in the following question: *given two distinct non-equivalent irreducible binary forms $F$ and $G$ of the same degree $d \geq 3$, same discriminant and content 1, when is it possible for them to represent primitively the same infinite subset of the integers?*

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Let $P_F$ (resp. $P_G$) be the set of primes primitively represented by $F$ (resp. $G$). Are you asking whether it is possible for $P_F = P_G$, or whether it is possible for $P_F \cap P_G$ to be infinite?

Comment: @DanielLoughran the condition that $P_F$ and $P_G$ consist of primes is too restrictive. Instead, let those two sets contain all numbers primitively represented by F and G, respectively. I'm asking under which conditions $P_F \cap P_G$ can be infinite.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Do you know examples of $F$ and $G$ where this property does *not* hold?

Comment: @DanielLoughran I do know an example when this is not true. Stanley Yao Xiao gave an example of two binary forms of degree 4 with coefficient vectors F=(2401,98,3,4,5) and G=(1,2,3,196,12005). They are not equivalent and don't have any GL2(Q)-automorphisms. However, they are connected by means of the relation F(x,7y)=G(7x,y), and because of that there are infinitely many integers which can be primitively presented by both forms.

Comment: Not the restrictions you wanted, but take a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/152889/positive-ternary-quadratic-forms-in-the-same-genus-that-represent-the-same-numbe  which, if ever proved, give counterexamples to a conjecture of Hsia that positive ternary quadratic forms are determined by their primitively represented numbers. I did check for primitivity, not sure i mentioned that in my original question.

Comment: If $d>4$ you could try applying the Bombieri-Lang conjecture to the projective surface defined by $F(x,y)=G(z,w)$ and see what you get.

Comment: @DanielLoughran I do not have an example of F and G which, under specified conditions, cannot primitively represent an infinite subset of the integers. I need to think about it, but I bet that such examples can be made. It was proved by Mahler in 1930's that irreducible binary forms of degree $\geq 3$ primitively represent only 0% of the integers. So I guess that if two thin sets that F and G represent intersect infinitely many times, then F and G should be connected to each other through some relation, like in the example above.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch thanks, for bringing this up. Rrecently Stanley Yao Xiao also pointed out to me that the problem I posed should be quite difficult, since it basically reduces to Bombieri-Lang Conjecture.

Comment: @Anton: Well you can come up with silly examples like $F(x,y) = x^{2n} + y^{2n}$ and $G(x,y) = - x^{2n} - y^{2n}$: these clearly do not simultaneously represent infinitely many integers. But of course here there is an obstruction at the real place. The interesting case is where there are no local obstructions, but as Felipe pointed out the problem here is essentially a special case of the Bombieri-Lang conjecture.